# Android Two layout with fixed width in the sides and one layout with fluid widht in the middle

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I need to make one row of a listview follows:
The row consists of three columns, the left has to contain a layout with background color and text in the center and on the right is the same but with an image. The middle layout will contain three lines of text
I need the two side layout have a fixed width and the middle layout has a width depending on the device resolution.

Example: https://www.dropbox.com/s/udn1lfo1hy6px44/Captura%20de%20pantalla%202015-02-06%20a%20las%201.png?dl=0

My code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/lytVoterNumber"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblVoterNumber"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="1999"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lytVoterData"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/lytVoterNumber"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lytVoterNumber">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Text Text Text"
            android:id="@+id/lblVoterLastName" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Text Text Text"
            android:id="@+id/lblVoterName" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Text Text Text"
            android:id="@+id/lblDni" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:id="@+id/lytIcono"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:minHeight="30dp"
        android:minWidth="30dp"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:src="@drawable/flecha"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: So, what problem are you facing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

check this

```
<LinearLayout  
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="10" >
```

this is a `LinearLayout` with `orientation` *horizontal* and it has a `weight sum` of **10** now all you have to do is split **10** into **3** and make the two side `Views` have the same proportion of the **10** and the rest will be the middle fella's proportion, so for eg, if you want a `TextView` as a child of this `linearLayout` give the `TextView` a `width` of *0dp* and a `weight` of 1 , the same goes with the other right `View`, same `weight` same `width` then 8/10 is left, so the 8/10 of the screen size is for you middle `View`

so your overall will look like this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:weightSum="10" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="8"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

get it, Sir?

Comment: Cool, this is what I need. 
The core are "weightSum" and "layout_weightSum".

Thank you